# Inequality query in the book of G. H. Hardy 'An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers'

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Book: An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers - G. H. Hardy and Chapter XXII

[image]

The last inequality is the one I don't understand

Can you help give me a hint?

Comment: Hint:-  The product representation of $\frac{\phi(n)}{n}$ is split at $r-\rho$.

Answer (score 1):

From the first inequality we have $\rho\log\log n <\log n$. So $0\le\rho<(\log n)/\log\log n.$ And we have $ 0<1-1/\log n<1.$  So $$(1-1/\log n)^{\rho} >(1-1/\log n)^{(\log n)/\log\log n}.$$ The other term $\prod_{p\le\log n}(1-1/p)$ in the last line is exactly the same thing as the term $\prod_{i=1}^{r-\rho}(1-1/p_i)$ in the line above it.

Comment: They are exactly the same by the definition of $p_1,...,p_{r-\rho}$.

Comment: I had a typo, The superscript in the product in the last line is now $r-\rho$.

Answer (score 0):

Hardy & Wright's book was published many decades ago, and I believe the confusion can be addressed if we formulate this problem in terms of a new set of notations.

$$
{\varphi(n)\over n}=\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac1p\right)
$$

We may introduce a parameter $t>0$ to partition the product into two parts:

\begin{aligned}
{\varphi(n)\over n}
&=\prod_{\substack{p|n\\p\le t}}\left(1-\frac1p\right)\prod_{\substack{p|n\\p>t}}\left(1-\frac1p\right) \\
&>\left(1-\frac1t\right)^{\omega(n,t)}\prod_{p\le t}\left(1-\frac1p\right)
\end{aligned}

where $\omega(n,t)=\#\{p|n:p>t\}$. By the properties of factorizations, we know trivially that $t^{\omega(n,t)}<n$. This indicates that $\omega(n,t)<\log n/\log t$. Plugging this into the above expression, we conclude

$$
{\varphi(n)\over n}>\left(1-\frac1t\right)^{\log n/\log t}\prod_{p\le t}\left(1-\frac1p\right)
$$

Finally, setting $t=\log n$ gives the inequality in Hardy & Wright's book. By the way, happy halloween!